# What pattern can I use to modify several child attributes on the same form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms

I have a Rails 3.2 project where:

```
Product has_many Descriptions
```

These `Descriptions` have a `description_type` and a `language_code`. Different types of `Products` can have different types and numbers of `Descriptions`, so that a `Product` of type 'Catalog`will have 4 different Descriptions, where a product of type`Wholesale` will have only 2.

Upon the creation of a `Product`, an `after_create` method creates the different `descriptions` for the product, filling in only the `description_type`. The idea is that the user then goes in and fills in the different description values.

Now I am in the situation where I have to dynamically build some complex form with a different number of descriptions, then pass all those description values via the controller to some class method on either `Product` or `Description` to persist the data, and it just ends up as spaghetti everywhere.

I am convinced that I'm thinking of the problem wrong. I can't unthink it though, as this is one box I seem to put myself in over and over.

Is there some pattern that I can apply to the problem domain of nesting these child attributes in an existing form? I have to do it on Edit, because I don't know how many fields to create until the `product_type` is chosen. Again, I'm open to doing this completely differently.

I always run into this problem, and it ties me in knots. I am convinced that I am approachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just today I had to rebuild a Member form in our app, where a `Member` belongs to a `User` which has many `PhoneNumber`s.

The `Member` model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user` and the `User` model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers`

Using the [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem, I am able to do the following in my Member form:

```
# phone number fields in members/_form.html.haml
# if you do use this on a new (know you said edit but just in case) ... be sure to instantiate the association
# in my case: @member.user.phone_numbers.build 
# u represents the User part of the form ... typically 'f'
= u.simple_fields_for :phone_numbers do |phone|
  = render 'users/phone_number_fields', f: phone
.add-phone-link-wrapper.pull-right
  = link_to_add_association 'Add Phone', u, :phone_numbers, class: 'btn btn-orange btn-mini add-remove-links', partial: 'users/phone_number_fields', render_options: { wrapper: 'bootstrap' }

# 'users/phone_number_fields' partial
.nested-fields
  = f.input :phone
  = f.input :phone_label, as: :select, collection: PhoneNumber::LABELS
  = f.input :display_number, as: :boolean
  = link_to_remove_association 'Remove Phone', f, class: 'btn btn-red btn-mini add-remove-links pull-right', render_options: { wrapper: 'bootstrap' }
```

Note: I use SimpleForm and cocoon has some differences in implementation depending on your form builder (all on their github page/wiki).

For our needs, this fit perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Craig, my Stegosaurus walnut-sized brain could not get past this one. I'm using `simple_form` as well, so that's great. `Cocoon` looks like a great alternative to `nested_form`.

Comment: Haha! I hear you! I've dealt with this one so many times and was pleased to find Cocoon ... hope it works for you as well as it has for me so far!